# Minimal laws that define each type class

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

Where can I find documentation about the minimum subset of laws that need be to check for a given type class instances to be correct?

For instance, I know from [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) that a `Monad` can be defined only using "the 3 Monad laws", and these will be sufficient to prove the laws "inherited from" from `Applicative` & `Functor`.

A concrete example where I'm struggling with is the [`CoflatMap`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/f1b088b147d1b1581bbe5167162d82b5a770b9c4/core/src/main/scala/cats/CoflatMap.scala) type class that I'm not really familiar with. What do I need to prove to make sure that it's correct? In [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats), [`CoflatMapLaws`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/f1b088b147d1b1581bbe5167162d82b5a770b9c4/laws/src/main/scala/cats/laws/CoflatMapLaws.scala) define 5 laws and inherits a bunch more laws from [`FunctorLaws`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/f1b088b147d1b1581bbe5167162d82b5a770b9c4/laws/src/main/scala/cats/laws/FunctorLaws.scala), but I'm assuming there is a smaller set that's sufficient to prove all other laws.

Comment: What is `CoflatMap` and where is it defined? What is cats?

Comment: `CoflatMap` looks to me like `Comonad` without `extract`.